# terminal shortcut for mail account switching using com.apple.mail.plist

Tags: macos, email, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts

## Environment: OS X 10.14.3

I am trying to set up a keyboard short cut for mail.app using a terminal command to write to the plist file.

In `Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts`, it is possible to set keyboard shortcuts to switch mail accounts. When set the short cut appears in the change mail menu when composing a new mail:

[image]

With these set, running `defaults read com.apple.mail.plist` generates this output:

```
{
    NSUserKeyEquivalents =     {
        "john doe \\U2013 john.doe@gmail.com" = "@~^d";
        "john doe2 \\U2013 john.doe2@gmail.com" = "@~^k";
        "john doe3 \\U2013 john.doe3@gmail.com" = "@~^g";
    };
}
```

If I delete one of this entries using the GUI interface in `Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts` and try and reset it using the following terminal command:

`defaults write com.apple.mail.plist NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add "john doe3 \\U2013 john.doe3@gmail.com" "@~^g"`

the entry appears correctly when I query `defaults read com.apple.mail.plist` but it does not work in Mail nor does it appear in the GUI interface.

Does anyone know why this is not working?

Comment: does mail relaunch help?

Comment: @MarekH: No. Also, when the change is made in the GUI, it is immediate. No need to relaunch the app

Comment: Hopper + lldb to see internals of Mail app. This will definitely answer how it works.

Comment: Thanks @MarekH but what is Hopper + lldb? I have never used them before.

Comment: @MarekH. hopperapp.com is an expensive option to just set up one terminal command. I think I need to find another solution but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Hopperapp has free option ;) Beside I have just opened Mail in hopperapp and I don't see Mail app anywhere reading user defaults for key NSUserKeyEquivalents. What should I do to make some action in mail app to get shortcut triggered?

Comment: It is still possible that NIB, XIB has binding to nsuserdefaultscontroller.

Comment: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20131123074223584 according to this your shortcut needs to be named exactly like menuitem action. It will just swap keyboard shortcut for named menu item

Comment: @MarekH: the shortcut is set in `Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts`. Add a new shortcut for the Mail.app and type the exact name as it appears in a new mail message in the from box. To insert the dash use `option + -`.

Comment: I think the only valid names are menu item names (top menu)

Comment: The name has to be the exact name as it appears in Mail.app. For example: `john doe – john.doe@gmail.com`

Comment: I can help but you need to send screenshot of your menu items. I have just tried it and new keyboard shortcut immediately appeared in Mail.app, you have just repeated my last comment

Comment: Do you understand I asked for your screenshot? It works here. I don't think I understand what you want to achieve correctly (or at which place). If you want help you need to cooperate

Comment: @MarekH: Did you add via the GUI or using defaults write?

Comment: Mareks-MacBook-Pro-2:Xcode xhruso00$ defaults write -app Mail NSUserKeyEquivalents '{"Take All Accounts Offline"="@^$n";}'
Mareks-MacBook-Pro-2:Xcode xhruso00$ defaults write -app Mail NSUserKeyEquivalents '{"Take All Accounts Offline"="@^$d";}'

Comment: Since you don't cooperate I am not helping you further. It all works and menu items show changed shortcuts instantly

Comment: @MarekH: Sorry, I did not mean to offend. Maybe my original answer was not clear. I am not trying to add a shortcut to a standard menu item. The shortcut allows the mailbox from account to be changed when composing a new email. I have amended the original question so hopefully it is clear.